# Passing secrets to web activity in Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure-keyvault, azure-data-factory

I am using web activity to get a bearer token from an authentication endpoint. I need to pass secrets such as user id and password in the header as below.

[Headers in web activity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cafNs.png)

I want to fetch user id and password from Azure key vault and pass it to web activity. Is there a way I can access the key vault in the expression?

Currently, I am fetching the secrets from an azure function and passing them as parameters to the pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

Currently you can´t access directly to Azure Key vault.
You can create a json file like:

```
{
  "IC-USER-ID": "abc",
  "IC-USER-PASSWORD": "abc123",
}
```

And read from it. In release process you can read the values from key vault and update json file. You have to ensure that only the right person can access the file.